# SQL SERVER Convert BLOB data to STRING

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to extract blob data from a SQL SERVER 2008 R2 database. The data is annotation data that an application stores. I have done some research and I have been partially successful in converting the data. I get about 20-30 first characters of each entry. 
This is the SQL statement I used:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(MAX), CONVERT(varbinary, blob)) from annotation_data;
```

How can I get all the data?

Comment: What data type is `blob`? If it is a `varbinary` already then you really don't need to cast it to `varbinary` before you cast it to `varchar`..

Answer (score 5):

The value truncates because you have not specified a length for the convert to `varbinary`. Without a specific length you get the [default which is `30`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks).

```
select convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary, '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'));
select convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'));
```

Result:

```
123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```